Unable to get path file ( not media ) using Intent
I have this code where basically i got a file path ( not a media one ), for some reason, in some Android 10 devices I´m getting the path as
/document/msf:<number>

In the manifest I have
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


    private val xfile = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        var xmlFile = FileWrapperFactory(requireContext()).getAssetFileWrapper("file")
        var xmlPath = ""
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            xmlPath = result.data?.data?.path.toString()
            xmlFile = FileWrapperFactory(requireContext()).getExternalFileWrapper(xmlPath)
        }
        viewBinding.pathName.setText(xmlPath)
    }

....

 fun getFile() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            .setType("*/*")
        xfile.launch(Intent.createChooser(intent, "file"))
    }


I need to change my code to that scenario, and I tried several solutions but no one succeeded.

Since your file type is not a media one, follow this official guide: Access documents and other files from shared storage
Update:
If you just need the URI, use this code:
private val readFile = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument()) { uri ->
    uri?.let { documentUri ->
        // use the URI here
    }
}

fun readFileContent() {
    val mimeTypes = arrayOf("*/*") // You can specify MIME types if needed
    readFile.launch(mimeTypes)
}


thanks @dev.tejasb, but i just need the uri, wich Intent should i use?

From Android 10, we cannot access file paths due to Scoped Storage restrictions. Hence, you need to update your code to handle URI instead of path & also get it ready for Scoped Storage. Use the link in answer for reference.

Try add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" into AndroidManifest.xml file.
